# Why isn't scala implicit def with higher order kind able to pick up my partial type?

Tags: scala

I hit an issue where scala implicit isnt' able to match a type declaration which is a partial application of a type of a higher order kind

```
implicit def extensions[F[_], A](m: F[A]) = new {
 def foundIt() = ()
}

case class Foo[T](x: T)
val f1: Foo[Int] = Foo(42)
f1.foundIt() // Implicit is able to match and infer
type FooType[T] = Foo[T]
val f2: FooType[Int] = Foo(42)
f2.foundIt() // Implicit is able to match and infer

case class Foo2[T, V](x: T, y: V)
val f3: Foo2[Int, Double] = Foo2(4, 2.0)
// f3.foundIt()  // Doesn't work of course
type Foo2Type[T] = Foo2[T,Double]
val f4 : Foo2Type[Int] = Foo2(42,2.0)
// f4.foundIt() // Why doesn't this work ...
extensions[Foo2Type,Int](f4).foundIt() //  if this works?
```

Is this a limitation of scala?  Are type declarations's kind not matchable and inferred by scala?

Comment: I'm not  sure, but I think you've hit https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2712 . Depends on what version of Scala you're using--if earlier than 2.11.9, then it's probably it. If so, try this out on 2.11.9 or later (e.g. 2.12.x).

Comment: I tested your exact code on various scala versions and it always works, so I am not convinced it is SI-2712. What scala version are you using?

Comment: This works for me.. but it would be better to make this an `implicit class` rather than a implicit conversion that strangely returns an anonymous class.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Because the code you provided does work on scala 2.10.6, 2.11.8 and 2.12.1.